# How to use a list in a when conditional in Ansible playbook

Tags: list, loops, ansible, conditional-statements

I'm trying to check if certain mount points have been added but only want to see those I added which are stored into `added_mounts`.

How to feed a list which is in a variable to a when conditional as in underneath example?

Sorry if my wording is not up to scratch but I'm still learning.

I'm using Ansible 2.9.

I've tried to use `vars_files` and make a list and place it in `./host_vars/test/added_mounts` or in `./vars/added_mounts` but it does not help.

I was thinking to try with a loop in the when conditional but underneath does not work.

```yaml
when: item.device == {{ item }}
loop: added_mounts
```

One item in the list works:

```yaml
- name: "check mounted directories"
  hosts: test
  vars:
    - added_mounts: '/dev/sda1'
  
  tasks:

    - name: Show only Mount point and device info
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.mount }} - {{ item.device }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.mount }} - {{ item.device }}"
      when: item.device == added_mounts
```

Several items in the list doesn't work:

```yaml
- name: "check mounted directories"
  hosts: test
  vars:
    - added_mounts:
        - '/dev/sda1'
        - '/dev/mapper/vg_abc-lv_abc'
  tasks:

    - name: Show only Mount point and device info
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.mount }} - {{ item.device }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.mount }} - {{ item.device }}"
      when: item.device == added_mounts
```

If anyone has any hints or pointing to the obvious, I would be most grateful.

Comment: `when: item.device in added_mounts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a hint in the comments to make a condition on your loop which answers your direct question.

Meanwhile you don't even need a condition in that case. You can select the existing mounts using your list directly from source using the `selectattr` filter. For a reference see [Data manipulation in ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) (where you will actually find [an example which almost perfectly matches your question](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html#find-mount-point)).

Here is an example:

```yaml
- name: Show only Mount point and device info
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.mount }} - {{ item.device }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts | selectattr('device', 'in', added_mounts) | list }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.mount }} - {{ item.device }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, changing the "==" for "in" does the job. Apparently the selectattr filter documentation links do not exist for version 2.9. When trying your solution above i get error: 
`FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <generator object select_or_reject at 0x7fa94f582468>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}`

Comment: See my edit above which wlll work with ansible version <2.10 and >=2.10 alike. Note that 2.9 is end of life since end of 2021 and that it is time to upgrade.

Comment: Tried it with list also, i get no error but also no output, the task is skipped. The added mounts are there in the system if i `mount|grep sda1` it's there. Anyway thanks for showing an alternative way and introducing me to the 'selectattr' filter. I'll try and make it work one day when i'll need more selectattr. We're stuck with version 2.9 until we upgrade some other tools also.

Comment: I had the wrong attribute in selectattr... Fixed. Next time please add in your question an example data. See [How to create a minimal complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve)